# Button that changes colour and disables temp whilst customer is in checkout

Tags: html, css, button, colors, action

I am wondering how I can make a store button that is Black that changes colour (blue)for a set amount of time when clicked (eg. 2 mins whilst customer is checking out) and then changes to a different colour (red) when that product has been bought. 
I hope I have explained it well, but this has been baffling me for ages, I know how to code a buy button for a product buy the whole changing colour is messing with my mind. 
this is the button i have this far -  https://codepen.io/ukswiftx/pen/wZwbXy `enter code here`
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is my button currently, https://codepen.io/ukswiftx/pen/wZwbXy

Answer (score 0):

I really hope my answer will help you or inspire you to find the final solution to your problem even though i did not fully understand your question

html button

```html
<input id="checkout" type="button" value="click" />
```

Javascript

```js
var col = "default";//keep the color string
setInterval(function() {
  if (col == "default") {
    $("#checkout").css("background-color", "blue");
    col = "blue";
  } else if (col == "blue") {
    $("#checkout").css("background-color", "red");
  } 
}, 3000);// 3 second interval you can change it to 12000 for 2 min
$("#checkout").on("click", function() { // on click change color to black
  $("#checkout").css("background-color", "black");
})
```

you can check the solution [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/talabe/toa5m1k8/3/)